# Fixing multiple Users permissions

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, apple-remote-desktop

In a classroom environment after a month without issues all of the sudden everyone is getting locked out of their folders, including my local admin user.

What works is logging into each user, elevated, I may run terminal command:

```
sudo find ~ $TMPDIR.. -exec chflags -h nouchg,nouappnd,noschg,nosappnd {} + -exec chown -h $UID {} + -exec chmod +rw {} + -exec chmod -h -N {} + -type d -exec chmod -h +x {} + 2>&-
```

This is from Linc Davis [Repairing permissions when owner is "Fetching..."](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6729832?tstart=0)

So how to use Apple Remote Desktop to fix this via UNIX script?

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /Users

# Create an array with a list of all users in the users folder excluding Shared, site, nc12, and g
full=$(ls -1 /Users/ | grep -v 'Shared\|site\|nc12\|g\|.localized')
echo Fixing Permissions....

# Loop permissions fix for the values of the array $full
for i in $full 
{
    cd /Users/$i
    find ~ $TMPDIR.. -exec chflags -h nouchg,nouappnd,noschg,nosappnd ;
    chown -h $UID
    chmod -R -N ~ $i
    chmod -R 700 $i
    chmod -R 777 $i/Public
    chmod -R 733 $i/Public/Drop\ Box
}

# A reboot shouldn't be necessary since the permissions change instantaneously and will be different the next time a program tries to access files.

# That said, it's never a bad idea to reboot
echo "You must REBOOT the machine to complete the process. Thank you."
exit
```

What may my syntax errors be? Other suggestions?

Comment: Which specific error message are you getting, on which line? And I assume you are aware that your script is not doing the same thing as the find command from above?

Comment: Possible issues: full is a list not an array and cannot handle spaces in file names. Instead of guessing which files should be excluded in `/Users` , test if the file system object is a valid home folder (`id` and `dscl`  could be used here). Unquoted variables through out the script. Missing escape or quotes in the find command. Missing operand in the `chown` statement. Duplicate operands in the `chmod` statement that strips the ACL's